# Selenium clicking a sub menu

Tags: selenium

I am Really stuck for the past two days here. I am trying to click sub menu and when I  try to click sub menu I get an errors as like the following

`Element not found for the sub menu.`

I have tried below code

```
WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.id("x-menu-el-P46915788081933044__folderbrowser_PJL"));
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

HTML Code

```
<li id="x-menu-el-P46915788081933044__folderbrowser_PJL" class="x-menu-list-item">
<a id="P46915788081933044__folderbrowser_PJL" class="x-menu-item" href="javascript:var abc = doNothing()" unselectable="on" hidefocus="true">
<img id="ext-gen926" class="x-menu-item-icon " src="netmarkets/images/import.gif">
<span id="ext-gen927" class="x-menu-item-text">Upload Documents from Compressed      File</span>
```

Comment: looks like the id is dynamically generated. are you sure it's always the same?

Comment: Yeah you are Right. ID is Dynamic.How to click this Dynamic id?

Comment: I prefer to use xpath, how about `//li[@id="x-menu-list-item"]`? or use chrome and right click, copy xpath, and check if that's useful

Comment: @user3678068: This is the Xpath I am getting "/html/body/div[27]/ul/li[3]/a/span" when i tried with this Xpath Still getting element not found.

Comment: perhaps, the element was generated after some user action like clicking some button. you can try `$x("/html/body/div[27]/ul/li[3]/a/span")` in chrome console right after the page loads, and see if you get anything. If not, then open the menu, and see the last command works now. There's a lot of trial and error in this.

Comment: yes you are Right again. The element is getting generated after clicking the previoud menu. here I am trying to click the sub-menu. This is the below code i used, still no success :(
    WebElement Compress = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[27]/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
         Compress.click();

Comment: you just need 2 clicks then :D

Comment: Two Clicks in sense. Did not catch you?

Comment: I mean have selenium click the menu, then the submenu

Comment: I tried with my mean of clicking the main menu first and then clicking the sub menu. for sub menu i am getting no element found.

Comment: maybe wait half second after the first click?

Comment: Thank you all It worked after giving wait. Thankyou very Much Guys. Code Used.
Thread.sleep(5000);
         WebElement Compress = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload Documents from Compressed File"));
         JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Compress);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ID you should probably use the class name.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.ClassName("x-menu-list-item"));
```

or you could try using the css selector

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[class='x-menu-list-item']"));
```

Since the above return multiple items you could just use to return the exact element that you need:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload Documents from Compressed File"));
```

Comment: The class is same for the other sub menus also. Will it work? This is teh xpath i am getting "/html/body/div[27]/ul/li[3]/a/span" still no

Comment: The ClassName and cssSelector name is same for the other submenus also.

Comment: What about `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Upload Documents from Compressed"))`

Comment: I used.
 WebElement Compress = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload Documents from Compressed File")); Still getting no such element.

Comment: Ok I've added that as the answer

Comment: Thank you all It worked after giving wait. Thankyou very Much Guys. Code Used. Thread.sleep(5000); WebElement Compress = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload Documents from Compressed File")); JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Compress);

Answer (score 0):

1st click on the menu and then try the following statement -

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='x-menu-list-item']//span[contains(text(),'Upload Documents from Compressed')])).click();
or directly try this -

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Upload Documents from Compressed')])).click();

I guess mostly the error is due to the span name spaces in between words, if the above dont work, pls attach a screenshot or give some details of the html code, so we can try more options, all d best.

Comment: HI Sunpat. It Worked with the following Code. Thread.sleep(5000); WebElement Compress = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload Documents from Compressed File")); JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Compress);  Actualy Wait was needed. Thank you for the reply